# Stacking context: absolute positioning and floats

Tags: css, css-float, z-index

[This MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_and_float) explains the stacking context and floats. Here is the example they provide:

```css
div {
  font: 12px Arial;
}
span.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#absdiv1 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 10px;
  right: 140px;
  border: 1px dashed #990000;
  background-color: #ffdddd;
  text-align: center;
}
#normdiv {
  /* opacity: 0.7; */
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px dashed #999966;
  background-color: #ffffcc;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
#flodiv1 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed #009900;
  background-color: #ccffcc;
  text-align: center;
}
#flodiv2 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 10px;
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed #009900;
  background-color: #ccffcc;
  text-align: center;
}
#absdiv2 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 130px;
  left: 100px;
  border: 1px dashed #990000;
  background-color: #ffdddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<br />
<br />

<div id="absdiv1">
  <br /><span class="bold">DIV #1</span>
  <br />position: absolute;
</div>

<div id="flodiv1">
  <br /><span class="bold">DIV #2</span>
  <br />float: left;
</div>

<div id="flodiv2">
  <br /><span class="bold">DIV #3</span>
  <br />float: right;
</div>

<br />

<div id="normdiv">
  <br /><span class="bold">DIV #4</span>
  <br />no positioning
</div>

<div id="absdiv2">
  <br /><span class="bold">DIV #5</span>
  <br />position: absolute;
</div>
```

In the example, `div#1` should belong to category 5 (Descendant positioned elements) and `div#3` should belong to category 3 (Floating blocks). So `div#1` should be over `div#3`. Why is it below in the example?

Comment: sorry. I don't know how to add the fancy inline content. Will learn it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Stacking order and opacity

The stacking order is affected by the `opacity` property. This is noted in the [article you linked to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_and_float):

> **Note:** In the example below, all the blocks except the non-positioned one, are translucent show the stacking order. If the opacity of the non-positioned block (DIV #4) is reduced, then something strange happens: the background and border of that block pops up above the floating blocks, but still under positioned blocks. I was not able to understand whether this is a bug or a peculiar interpretation of the specifications. (Applying opacity could implicitly create a stacking context.)

### Testing this theory

Let's reduce the markup to include just the two divs in question. Here is the scenario we see; the absolutely positioned `div1` is underneath `div3`:

[image: Screenshot 1]

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
}
#div1 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  border: 1px dashed #990000;
  background-color: #ffdddd;
  text-align: center;
}
#div3 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed #009900;
  background-color: #ccffcc;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  DIV #1
  <br>position: absolute;
</div>



<div id="div3">
  DIV #3
  <br>float: right;
</div>
```

Now, let's remove the `opacity` properties (specifically the one on `div3`). The stacking order is now as you expect it to be:

[image: Screenshot 2]

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
}
#div1 {
  /*opacity: 0.7;*/
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  border: 1px dashed #990000;
  background-color: #ffdddd;
  text-align: center;
}
#div3 {
  /*opacity: 0.7;*/
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed #009900;
  background-color: #ccffcc;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  DIV #1
  <br>position: absolute;
</div>



<div id="div3">
  DIV #3
  <br>float: right;
</div>
```

#### Read more

[Here is an in-depth write-up](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) on how the `opacity` property affects the stacking order.

Comment: This should be the answer for the question.  My understanding is this.

Comment: This should be the answer for the question.  My understanding is this:  
If there is no opactiy, positioned elment(div1) is before float element(div3).

If there is opacity, both elements are at the same level. They are displayed by their order in the html source.  Once you have opacity, the postioned/float rule is ignored.